# Stop script and log error

Tags: logging, powershell, error-handling

I have a powershell script that needs to read from a config file with a simple Get-Content cmdlet:

```
 foreach ($s in Get-Content $config_file)
```

If the config file is not where it is supposed to be I want to stop the script and log the error.

Is it possible to use the -ErrorAction with a cusom logging function with in the script?

```
foreach($s in Get-Content $config_file -ErrorAction mdie('Could not find config file')
```

*mdie* is a logging function that logs the error and exits the script.

Or is there a better way?

-G

Comment: What is "exits the script"? Return or just fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-ErrorAction Stop` and `try..catch` pattern. In the `catch` block an error object is represented by the variable `$_`.

```
function LogErrorAndExit([string]$message) {
    Write-Host $message -ForegroundColor Red
    exit 1
}

try {
    foreach($s in Get-Content $config_file -ErrorAction Stop) {
        # normal code
        # ...
    }
}
catch {
    # error case code
    LogErrorAndExit $_
}

# normal code
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Is there no way to achieve this with out using a try-catch block?

Comment: You can also use the `trap` statement. I prefer `try/catch/finally` way, it seems to be simpler and yet more flexible. But you cannot assign a function as an error action, this concept does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something a little more simple

```
param($configfile)
$qwe=gc $configfile -erroraction silentlycontinue -errorvariable errorxd
if($qwe -ne $null)
{
  # Here comes what ever do you want to do with the content
}
else
{
  # Here comes the call to the Error Log function
  # You could use the $errorxd variable to see what problem occurs, something like
  # LogError($errorxd)
}
```

Comment: It is good but.. What if the reason of failure is not "missing file or null content"? `$Error[0]` can help *sometimes* but what if 2+ errors happen? `$Error[0]` is not the first (normally most important).

Comment: @RomanKuzmin can you give me a example of 2+ errors? I'm thinking about but I can't imagine that situation

Comment: @RomanKuzmin I edited the gc call including the errorvariable parameter to add to the error log the description of a possible problem

Comment: 1) It is a very good idea to use ErrorVariable. 2) No, I cannot give an example of 2+ errors in this case. But who can guarantee that it is not possible? From my experience and mistakes, actual number of errors is sometimes larger than one can expect. I never assume that error count is 1.

Answer (score 0):

I would first test if the config file exist:

```
 if(-not (Test-Path -Path $config_file -PathType Leaf))
 {
    mdie('Could not find config file')
    exit 1
 }

 foreach ($s in Get-Content $config_file)
 ...
```

Comment: What if it exists but is locked by another app? :)